# My array members are null even though they are initialized

Tags: java

So I'm trying to access members inside my relation array, once it has been initialized. However it does not let me do so. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class FamilyRelations {
private Relationship [] relation;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FamilyRelations family = new FamilyRelations(); 

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(test);
    family.run(scanner);    
}

private void run(Scanner scanner) {


    noOfRelations = 3;
    relation= new Relationship [3];
    System.out.println(relation[0].child); // Why does this raise nullpointerexception?
     // Here I want to do relation[0].father = "John"; for example



}

public class Relationship {

public String child;
public String father;
public String mother;

public Relationship() {
    this.child = "hej";
    this.father = "father";
//  this.mother = mother;
}
```

Comment: Only the array is initialized. The array is full of empty slots. You need to create the objects inside it too.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem :)